# Why VisualState Selected no work in listviewitem?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Here is the XAML:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="TaskListView" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"  Value="Stretch"></Setter>                               
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0" Background="#00FF0000" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False">
                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                    <Setter Value="#2c567b" Target="InnerBorder.BorderBrush"/>
                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                    <Setter Value="White" Target="InnerBorder.BorderBrush"/>
                                                    <Setter Value="White" Target="InnerBorder.Background"/>
                                                    <Setter Value="#db4662" Target="InnerTextBlock.Foreground"/>
                                                    <Setter Value="#db4662" Target="InnerRectangle.Fill"/>
                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="#2c567b" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="InnerBorder"></Border>
                                    <Grid Padding="20,20,0,20" Name="InnerG">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="#30fff8" Margin="10" Name="InnerRectangle"></Rectangle>
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Foreground="#30fff8" Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding ProductName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

When I just create a controltemplate of listviewitem,it works.But after I add/edit it to DataTemplate,it failed.

I am sorry about that I am a beginner of UWP and hardly find a sample both create controltemplate/add it to datatemplate of listviewitem.

Would you please help me?Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you can follow @Martin 's answer to create ListView's ItemContainerStyle then change ListViewItem's ControlTemplate, so the `PointerOver` and `Normal` VisualState will be something like this:

```xml
 <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
     <VisualState.Setters>
         <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
         <Setter Target="Root.Foreground" Value="#30fff8"/>
         <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
     </VisualState.Setters>
 </VisualState>
 <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
 <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
     <VisualState.Setters>
         <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
         <Setter Target="Root.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
         <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
     </VisualState.Setters>
 </VisualState>
```

We change the `Root.Foreground` in the `PointerOver` and `Normal` VisualState. **Please delete your TextBlock's `Foreground="#30fff8"` code in your DataTemplate** as @David's comment.

On the other hand, you can also get the default ListViewItem's style from the C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\{SDK version}\Generic\generic.xaml file. You can copy the style of x:Key="ListViewItemExpanded" into your Page.Resource and remove the x:Key="ListViewItemExpanded", then this style will be applied to all the ListViewItems in your page. Then you can find the `Normal` and `PointerOver` Visualstate to make some change as you want. Also note that to **delete your TextBlock's `Foreground="#30fff8"` code in your DataTemplate**.

---Update---

Here I paste all the xaml code here from the first scenario, you can try it.

```xml
<Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListViewItemRevealStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForeground}"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
            <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,0,12,0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinWidth}"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMinHeight}"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <ListViewItemPresenter x:Name="Root" CheckBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBrush}" ContentMargin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" CheckBoxBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckBoxBrush}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" CheckMode="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckMode}" DragOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}" DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackground}" DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForeground}" FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderBrush}" FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}" FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusSecondaryBorderBrush}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" PressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPressed}" PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackground}" PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundPointerOver}" PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver}"  ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" SelectedForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemForegroundSelected}" SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled}" SelectedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelected}" SelectedPressedBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed}" SelectedPointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.Foreground" Value="#30fff8"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointerOver"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverPressed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Target="Root.RevealBorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </ListViewItemPresenter>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle1" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemRevealStyle}" TargetType="ListViewItem"/>
    </Page.Resources>

<Grid>
        <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemContainerStyle1}" Name="TaskListView" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0" AllowFocusOnInteraction="False" >
                        <Border BorderThickness="4" BorderBrush="#2c567b" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="InnerBorder"></Border>
                        <Grid Padding="20,20,0,20" Name="InnerG">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle Fill="#30fff8" Margin="10" Name="InnerRectangle"></Rectangle>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding ProductName}" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                            <!-- You can add other controls and bind data-->
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you,I know your meaning.You mean I should create the controltemplate in ItemContainerStyle but not in DataTemplate,right?However,I need to binding 
 several data in it,not only just this ProductName,but how can I do it in DataTemplate if I don't create controltemplate in DataTemplate?

Comment: No, modifying the `ItemContainerStyle` will change the item container style, you could still create DataTemplate in your ListView to bind other data, I have updated my answer with more detailed code.

Comment: Now I knowed!ItemContainerStyle for VisualState  and DataTemplate for binding!That's great!Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when you define `VisualStates` like this, they belong to the inner `Grid` element, which actually does not have any `Selected` state defined. When you check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx), you can see that `Selected` state is defined on the `ListViewItem` control which acts as a wrapper around your actual "items" (content generated from the data template). So you should instead create a custom style for `ListViewItem` and assign it to `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`.

You can modify the style in multiple ways, but the easiest is to put the `ListView` on a page, right-click it in the **Designer** or **Document Outline**, and choosing **Edit additional templates**, **Edit Generated Item Container** and finally **Edit a copy...**. this will generate a copy of the default `ListViewItemStyle` which you can freely modify based on your preferences.

Comment: I followed your way,but now the problem is can't binding data to code-behind.How can I solve this,thank you.

Comment: You should keep your `DataTemplate` as it is, so binding should be done there. The `VisualStates` are for the "container" only

Comment: That's what I am bothering,my visualstates need to change the textblock foreground when mouse over,and the textblock need binding data to code-behind also.I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: @102425074 ListViewItem also has a Foreground property (inherited from Control). It will be used by the inner TextBlock as long as the TextBlock doesn't have Foreground explicitly set.

Comment: @DavidOliver I understand your meaning,however I wanna to find a way that can custom mouseover easily,as like setting mouseover trigger in controltemplate in wpf.

Comment: @MartinZikmund I tried a whole day,and follow the sample you showed in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 which contains VisualState.However after running the sample,the VisualState Selected still no works.

Answer (score 0):

@Martin Had already explained the solution for this, but as you mentioned that you are a beginner I would like to point out few things which might help you.

Please refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx) MSDN doc which has Styles and Template defined for a `ListView`.

In `ListView` style you will find Selected Visual State as below, you can modify that state as per your need.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Selected">
              <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MultiSelectCheck"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 Duration="0:0:0"
                                 To="1"/>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 Duration="0"
                                 To="1"/>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBackground" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
              </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```